# A quick way to compute the average of multiple timeseries?

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I'm writing the K-Means algorithm in Python with Numpy. The distance-to-all-centroids part is pretty optimized (compute with matrix of centroids instead of each one separately), but I'm struggling with the compute-new-centroid part. I'm copying the data per centroid from the dataset to compute the mean.

I think it will be faster without copying. How do I do this in Python/Numpy?

Code snippet:

```
    for c_i in range(k):
        sub_data = np.zeros([n_per_c[c_i],data_width])

        sub_data_i = 0
        for data_i in range(data_length):
            if label[data_i] == c_i:                    
                sub_data[sub_data_i,:] = data[data_i,:]
                sub_data_i += 1

        c[c_i] = np.mean(sub_data, axis=0)
```

c is a list of the centroids I have, data is the entire dataset, label is the list with classlabels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does the same as your code, without any explicit intermediate array:

```
for c_i in range(k):
    c[c_i] = np.mean(data[label == c_i, :], axis=0)
```

Getting rid of that last loop is tougher, but this should work:

```
label_counts = np.bincount(label)
label_sums = np.histogram2d(np.repeat(label, data_length),
                            np.tile(np.arange(data_length), k),
                            bins=(k, data_length),
                            weights=data.ravel())[0]
c = label_sums / label_count[:, None]
```

Comment: Thanks Jaime! The first solution already speeds up the code from 1 minute to under a second.
Can you explain what the second solution does? I can't really wrap my head around it.

Comment: `label_counts` is a count of how many times each label appears. I know need the sum of the values for each label and column. `data.ravel()` is your `data` array flattened, with all rows concatenated one after the other. `np.repeat(label, data_length)` indexes the label of each individual data entry. Similarly, `np.tile(np.arange(data_length), k)` indexes the column number. The call to `np.histogram2d` with that size bins simply sums together all values with a same label and column, and returns it in the right shape. Lastly, divide these sums by the counts, broadcasting counts to the whole row.